# Org-Agenda day agenda filtered by tags OR'ed

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-tags, filtering

A custom Agenda view can be filtered by tags AND'ed, e.g. show entries having both `play` **AND** `read` tags, like this:

```
(setq
 org-agenda-custom-commands
 '(("p" "play AND read" agenda ""
    ((org-agenda-tag-filter-preset '("+play" "+read"))))))
```

What could be the way to display **day agenda** listing entries with either `play` **OR** `read` tags?

Comment: This question looks like it is identical to [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35920/org-weekly-agenda-filter-tags-with-logical-or) where I have recently posted an answer.